# Reasons to use a sharepoint calendar over outlook

Tags: 2010, calendar

I am trying to sell using SharePoint calanders to the business. How would you go about using SharePoint calnders over Outlook. What advantages does it bring over creating outlook events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint calendars doesn't replace the outlook calendars. It's for a different use, especially for Sharing a calendar among several users just with the browser.

There are some advantages for the SharePoint, because the  calendar is based on a SharePoint list, you can enjoy from all the list capabilities such as the ability to add fields, views, manage permissions, exposure in SharePoint search results, ranking and more.